# Как правильно писать?

Tags: правописание

Здравствуйте. У меня вопрос не столько как правильно писать, но почему правильно писать нужно именно так. Вопрос выглядит абсурдным, и я заранее за него извиняюсь, но это важно. Вот фраза: "Если б ты только знала, через что мне приходится перешагивать". Имеются в виду внутренние моральные принципы, то бишь перешагивать через принципы. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется совершенно очевидным, что правильно писать нужно именно так: через ЧТО мне приходится перешагивать. Но оппонент, с большими претензиями на глубокое знание русского языка, настаивает, что правильно надо писать: через ЧЕГО мне приходится перешагивать. Скажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки правильно, и главное, почему?

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, "через что". И Вы очень верно подметили, Вам оппонент именно что с претензиями. В данном случае наблюдаем винительный падеж: "кого? что?" То есть, либо перешагивать через кого-то, либо — через что-то.
Никого не слушайте, Вы написали все правильно!

Answer (score 2):

Перешагивать через КОГО? ЧТО? - винительный падеж. Поэтому Вы правы - "через ЧТО мне приходится перешагивать".

Ну или через КОГО - в крайнем случае. )))

Answer (score 0):

Не отвечайте ему, сам со временем поймет.....

Answer (score 0):

Через "что". И лучше, пожалуй, "переступать", а не "перешагивать".

Comment: Ну и сама фраза "Если б ты знала", звучала бы благозвучнее в виде: "Если БЫ ты знала".

Answer (score 0):

"Через что".
"Через чего" - это только про задницу.